# React Native can't find variable Navigation in useLayoutEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```html
 export default function Main({navigation}) { 
  
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <Ionicons name={'settings-sharp'} size={30} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}/>
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```

The error raised is 'can't find variable: navigation'. 'navigation.setOptions' seems to be fine only the 'navigation.navigate' inside the onpress. I'm new to react native and the ES6 syntax. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your component expects to get `navigation` as a prop but it doesn't.  I can't say why from this component code alone, but you can access `navigation` from the `useNavigation` hook instead of from props.

Comment: Wouldn't the navigation.setOptions working mean that the component is receiving props? I'm also able to use navigation later inside my return statement.

Comment: To be honest I assumed that you mistaken when you said that `navigation.setOptions` was ok.  But if it's working elsewhere that's definitely suspicious.  Can you reproduce the error in an Expo Snack or CodeSandbox?  I don't see anything wrong with just the code that's posted here.

Comment: Managed to figure it out while trying to make a min reproduction. Turns out it was the component I was navigating to that was missing the navigation prop. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!